# AngularJS minError Uncaught Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a new AngularJS project I've just set up. I've installed `angular` and `angular-resource` via `bower` and all's good. I've installed another service I've used before - https://github.com/Fundoo-Solutions/angularjs-modal-service but when I inject the module it causes the error below:

> Uncaught object

It's pointing to the return statement of this function in AngularJS:

```
function minErr(module) {
  return function () {
    var code = arguments[0],
      prefix = '[' + (module ? module + ':' : '') + code + '] ',
      template = arguments[1],
      templateArgs = arguments,
      stringify = function (obj) {
        if (typeof obj === 'function') {
          return obj.toString().replace(/ \{[\s\S]*$/, '');
        } else if (typeof obj === 'undefined') {
          return 'undefined';
        } else if (typeof obj !== 'string') {
          return JSON.stringify(obj);
        }
        return obj;
      },
      message, i;

    message = prefix + template.replace(/\{\d+\}/g, function (match) {
      var index = +match.slice(1, -1), arg;

      if (index + 2 < templateArgs.length) {
        arg = templateArgs[index + 2];
        if (typeof arg === 'function') {
          return arg.toString().replace(/ ?\{[\s\S]*$/, '');
        } else if (typeof arg === 'undefined') {
          return 'undefined';
        } else if (typeof arg !== 'string') {
          return toJson(arg);
        }
        return arg;
      }
      return match;
    });

    message = message + '\nhttp://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.18/' +
      (module ? module + '/' : '') + code;
    for (i = 2; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      message = message + (i == 2 ? '?' : '&') + 'p' + (i-2) + '=' +
        encodeURIComponent(stringify(arguments[i]));
    }

    return new Error(message);
  };
}
```

I think it's saying that `Error` doesn't exist?

Am I missing a module or something?

Comment: Turns out the reason it was trying to create an error was I hadn't loaded the services' JS file. But I'm guessing that shouldn't have caused an error though?

Comment: Regarding the not.so verbose error message see here if you are using Chrome: [http://www.congral.com/2014/05/29/have-you-already-encountered-the-uncaught-object-exception/]. There are workarounds if you look for them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the reason why a person get this error with Angular. The module that you have included is not injected properly. For example, you must inject it as a Dependency injection properly before using that. So, please make sure that it's done.

And another reason is properly define `ng-app="<app-name>"` and make sure that the file in which you have written your Angular application code, for example: `angular.module('<app-name>', [])` is included as the script file.

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Thought it was weird that it causes an issue in the angular.js file