# Django-Angular CRUD operations

Tags: javascript, python, django, angularjs

I am using a custom library called [Django-Angular](https://github.com/jrief/django-angular) to perform basic CRUD operations in my Django template.

I am following the [official documentation](http://django-angular.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basic-crud-operations.html), but am unable to query for Django objects using Angular JS in my template - it is simply just displaying the Angular JS template tag {{ property.name }} and I am receiving an Angular JS `Uncaught object` error, which points to angular.js file ([this is the code block that it points to](http://pastebin.com/KRznZ4Zm), it points to the 1st line).

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292121/angularjs-minerror-uncaught-object), the module is not injected properly, thats where I need some help.

When following the tutorial I have set up a Django view:

`class PropertyMapView(NgCRUDView):
    model = Property
    fields = ['name',]`

added an URLparameter:

`url(r'^crud/property/?$', PropertyMapView.as_view(), name='property_map_view'),`

And this is my template:

```
  <body ng-app="myServices">

    {% verbatim %}

    <script type="text/javascript">


    var myServices = angular.module('myServices', ['ngResource']);

    myServices.factory('Property', ['$resource', function($resource) {
        return $resource('/crud/property/', {'pk': '@pk'}, {
        });
    }]);



    myServices.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'Property', function ($scope, Property) {
    // Query returns an array of objects, MyModel.objects.all() by default
    $scope.models = Property.query();

    // Getting a single object
    var property = Property.get({pk: 1});

    }]);

    </script>

    <div ng-controller="myCtrl" >
        <h2>Test: {{ property.name }} </h2>
        or
        <h2>Test: {{ property }} </h2>
    </div>

    {% endverbatim %}
```

By the way, I think that the view itself works, because when I am querying for `http://myurl.com/crud/property/`, I am receiving some data in the browser:

`[{"pk":1,"name":"Pastatas A"},{"pk":4,"name":"hmgbjmnbm"},{"pk":3,"name":"gfghfghfg"},{"pk":5,"name":"sdfsdgsdgsdgasssss"}]`.

I am just unable to set up the javascript part and make it work - as I said, it is simply just displaying the Angular JS template tag {{ property.name }} and I am receiving an Angular JS `Uncaught object` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that ng module was not loading properly because it was not installed.

`<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.19/angular-resource.js"></script>`

And I fixed my controller. One should write:

`$scope.property = Property.get({pk: 1});`

instead of:

`var property = Property.get({pk: 1});`

It seems that it works now!